# how to find facebook page is restricted page using graph api or FQL?

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, rest-client

Is it possible to get extra detail about page restriction using Graph API or FQL ?

https://www.facebook.com/DUFoodandDrink

I'm using app access token and RestClient GEM to get facebook page detail in background.

```
Response for certain page is,
{
 "error": {
 "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
 "type": "GraphMethodException", 
 "code": 100
  }
}
```

I could not get extra detail about why it's fail. how to find this page is restricted ?

Any suggestion ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

That error you received means your method that you passed to Facebook is invalid. You can test your methods at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer. Just passing a {page-id} or {page-name} to the Facebook API should return you the page information.

Here is the results for the page you posted in your question:

```
{
  "about": "Making life at Trinity taste better. ", 
  "can_post": true, 
  "category": "Food/beverages", 
  "description": "We put on different foodie events every week for our members; tastings, cookery classes, group dinners, foodie films and more. We also offer a smorgasbord of wonderful deals with our wonderful business partners so you'd be silly not to join.", 
  "is_published": true, 
  "location": {
    "street": "Room 3, The Atrium, Trinity College", 
    "city": "Dublin, Ireland", 
    "zip": ""
  }, 
  "talking_about_count": 36, 
  "username": "DUFoodandDrink", 
  "website": "www.dufoodanddrink.com", 
  "were_here_count": 0, 
  "id": "210187492372997", 
  "name": "DU Food and Drink", 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/DUFoodandDrink", 
  "likes": 2283, 
  "cover": {
"cover_id": 660580360667039, 
    "source": "https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/t1.0-9/s720x720/1924493_660580360667039_1641564952_n.jpg", 
    "offset_y": 56, 
    "offset_x": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: _“That error you received means your method that you passed to Facebook is invalid.”_ – no, it doesn’t. Facebook responds with this exception (also) if the requesting party does not have the rights to access the object in question. And if a page is restricted in any way (age, alcohol related content, region, …) then it can’t be accessed with an _app_ access token, because that doesn’t allow FB to check whether the user “behind” it would be allowed to access the page or not.

Comment: @CBroe you must not understand what the word invalid means or possibly I was not clear enough, but if the Facebook API call you made came back unsupported than it is an invalid request. Which is why I posted the link to the graph explorer so they can test the UID's and access tokens for the app to work.

Comment: It does _not_ (necessarily) mean that the _method_ is invalid, as you said. As I explained, this also happens when trying to access an object that the current access token does not have permission to see.

Comment: And that is exactly the case here – try the request you are suggesting _with an app access token_, and you will see that you get exactly that result: “Unsupported get request.”

Comment: Yes but in the graph explorer I only need to grant the basic profile access token to see the data of the page. And there is no field to request the specific data of the restrictions but it may be that Facebook does this automatically based on birthday. I don't know for sure. I couldn't find any documentation on the subject matter.

Comment: As I said: It makes a difference here whether you try to request this ID with a _user_ access token or an _app_ access token (and the latter is what the OP is trying), _because_ the page is restricted.

Comment: How can I get page detail either I used page access token or app access token. It's still showing "Unsupported get request". How can I know this page is restricted in Graph Explorer.